# how to get updated hidden field value using Selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the hidden field value using below code but getting the default value as `0.69163`.

```
WebElement hiddenInput = ieDriver.findElement(By.id("form_base_amount_input_hidden"));
String currencyConverted = hiddenInput.getAttribute("value");
```

old value:

```
<input name="base_amount" id="form_base_amount_input_hidden" value="0.69163" type="hidden">
```

new value:

```
<input name="base_amount" id="form_base_amount_input_hidden" value="383.852" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think only via JavaScriptExecutor:

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) ieDriver;
String script = "document.getElementsById('form_base_amount_input_hidden')[0].setAttribute('value', '383.852');");
je.executeScript(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String  text = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementsByName('base_amount')[0].value;");
```

Please execute this statement, hope you will get your result.